# How can I use different type of cell in collection view?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying create an app about social network. In there users can send two different type post (like image post or text post). Users selecting of their post type in another controller and create their post. I Created two different cell and want to call in cellForItemAt with if statement. The problem is how can I know users selection about post type ?

```
// there is users post type selection with button
let writeButton: UIButton = {

    let wButton = UIButton()
    wButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    wButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "writing"), for: .normal)
    wButton.setTitle("Writing", for: .normal)
    wButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    wButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic", size: 18)
    wButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    wButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    wButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedWriteButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    return wButton
}()

@objc func tappedWriteButton () {
    let writePost = WriteTitlePost()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(writePost, animated: true)
}

let mediaButton: UIButton = {

    let mButton = UIButton()
    mButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    mButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    mButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "photography"), for: .normal)
    mButton.setTitle("Media Post", for: .normal)
    mButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    mButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic", size: 18)
    mButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    mButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    mButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    mButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedMediaButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    return mButton
}()

@objc func tappedMediaButton() {


    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let mediaPost = MediaPost(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mediaPost)
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: nope when I clicked write button it is already calling  tappedWriteButton() . I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: Huh, IDK how, but I must have completely scrolled past it and misread it. I swear I thought both button's targets are `tappedMediaButton`. I'm going to slowly step away from my computer now.

Comment: no problem, you need some rest bro :D